# filter es6 accept a function as condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm stuck on a tutorial.

Q: Create a function called 'reject'.  Reject should work in the opposite way of 'filter' - if a function returns 'true', the item should *not* be included in the new array.  you have to use filter.

For example:

```
var numbers = [10, 20, 30];
var lessThanFifteen = reject(numbers, function(number){
  return number > 15;
}); 
console.log(lessThanFifteen) // [ 10 ];
```

My failed attempts

```
function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {
  array.filter(number => !iteratorFunction(number));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reject function should return the new array

```
function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {
  return array.filter(number => !iteratorFunction(number));
}
```